# Is it possible to change the field character limit in Audience Manager?

Tags: 2013, cme, audience-manager

I've updated the value of the ImportSource of each contact in AudienceManager to use "Website-" but what I didn't realize is that the field has a character limit of 10 which prevents publications with more than 2 digit ID to work.

Is there a way to change the field character limit in Audience Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. These fields are meant to be customized to suit your needs.
The "Import source" (also known as IDENTIFICATION_SOURCE) is just one of the example fields that are provided out-of-the-box and happens to be useful for most people.

The field will need to be updated in a few tables in the database, both on the Content Manager and on your presentation system(s).

For more information, refer to the following section of the documentation:

[Custom Contact extended details](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E4596A79-2FD5-43DF-9BA9-F6B304D3EFAF)

Comment: Is this supported via an update? Because I'm concerned that future updates would overwrite data that I've specified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you change the size in the database to be bigger than 10, you won't lose any data since it can all be contained in the new size.